# Get Final Uri which i am creating dynamically( guzzel)

Tags: laravel-5, guzzle6

Hi I want to get final URI which I am calling; I want to know which URI I am calling because I am creating the URI dynamically. This is the code I tried but something failed. I am using the latest version Of Guzzel

http://docs.guzzlephp.org/en/latest/index.html

```
public function index(Request $request)
{   
    $firstName = '{% First Name %}';
    $lastName = '{% Last Name %}';
    $emailID = '{% Email ID %}';
    $mobileNumber = '{% Mobile Number %}';
    $sms = urldecode($request->input('sms'));

    foreach (json_decode(substr(urldecode($request->input('messages')), 0, -6)) as $user) 
    {
        $smsText = $sms;

        if(strpos($sms, $firstName) != false || strpos($sms, $lastName) != false || strpos($sms, $emailID) != false || strpos($sms, $mobileNumber) != false)
        {             
            $smsText = str_replace($firstName, explode(" ",$user->field_full_name_value)[0], $smsText);
            $smsText = str_replace($lastName, explode(" ",$user->field_full_name_value)[1], $smsText);
            $smsText = str_replace($emailID, $user->mail, $smsText);
            $smsText=str_replace($mobileNumber, $user->field_phone_no_value, $smsText);
        }

        $response = $this->client->request(null,'/api/sendmsg.php',
                    ['query'=>[
                               ['user' => 'ray'],
                               ['pass' => 'as'],
                               ['sender' => 'abc'],
                               ['phone' => 7411220923], //$user->field_phone_no_value
                               ['text' => 'Test Message'], //$smsText
                               ['priority' => 'ndnd'],
                               ['stype' => 'normal']
                    ]]);           
    }  
}
```

Comment: Can you provide more info, like errors you get or incorrect and expected output?

Comment: i am not getting any error but i want to get the final uri which i have to call for bhash sms